# Can I get a full-time job in Germany but ask the German company to sign contract with my own corporate in Canada instead of myself?

Tags: taxes, canada, germany, canada-revenue-agency

I found a full-time job and I am moving to Germany. I've established a corporate in Canada and did some consultant job through it. Is it possible for the Germany company to sign the contract with my corporate in Canada?
What will be the tax complications?

Comment: One non-tax complication is that in Germany, health care is provided by the employer.  But you are making things so that you don't have a German employer.  As such, you may find it difficult to access health care.  You personally will be expected to pay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I see that. But I am more wondering if it is considered as tax fraud in Germany.

Comment: Why would you do that? What advantage do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, if the company agrees to it then it is possible.

Your Canadian Corporation will have to register a branch office in Germany (Zweigniederlassung) and pay taxes on the German income.  If your corporation pays you as an employee it will also be liable for German Payroll Tax and Social Security Contributions.

You personally will be liable for German Tax on any income assuming you are a resident in Germany.

It may be easier to register a German corporation (GmbH or UG (Haftungsbeschränkt) than to operate as a Canadian Corporation.

The German tax system can be complicated, especially if your German isn't great. Consulting a German Tax Advisor (Steuerberater) would be advised.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the issue, based on what I learned when looking into the opposite direction (I'm freelancer and business owner based in Germany, who will provide a course in Canada soon)

- My chamber of commerce (IHK) was very helpful (that's what they are for) and put me into contact with the [Canadian German Chamber of Industry and Commerce](http://kanada.ahk.de/en/) who are specialized on questions of trade between Germany and Canada, and have an official status to this at least from the German side.
- My *educated guess* is that you can sell services in Germany *without* setting up a full German branch.
  I can offer my services in Canada without, and such procedures are typically set down in reciprocal tax treaties. There is a German-Canadian tax treaty in any case.
- If you sell a service such as consulting in person in Germany that is subject to German VAT (Umsatzsteuer, USt).
- Usually the seller hands over USt to the tax office, and this means you'd need a German tax number which also means that you'll have to file German VAT declarations in future (I got the same options for Canada.). A branch office in Germany is probably not necessary, but already without that you'll have a lot of burocratic hassle.
- However, there's a 2nd option that is routinely used by businesses that *buy* from private persons (who do not have a VAT no.). In this case, a reverse bill is written by the *buyer* (German: Gutschrift, aka self-billing) who also withholds the VAT for the tax office.
  This is the possibility I'll also be using in Canada: a university will act as intermediate who give me such a reverse bill where the appropriate Canadian taxes are already subtracted (and they bill the participants of the course, this isn't as much hassle as it sounds as this course belongs to a conference, so the participants are anyways billed for the conference fee). In my German tax declaration I list the course as activity that is not subject to German VAT (as it takes place in a foreign country).
  Considering that this is a once-off situation and that the university (my direct customer) does have a VAT-ID so they can do the reverse billing procedure this is much easier and (hopefully) less hassle than getting VAT-ID for myself.

---

One totally different legal consideration you need to take care of is **Scheinselbständigkeit** (apparent-only freelancing). In Germany, any service contract that is in its content too close to an employment contract is legally considered an employment contract. If that happens, your customer is liable for the social insurance, and they'll be prosecuted for social insurance fraud.
The legal situation is quite messy an unpredictable in that respect.
This may very well mean that your customer/employer will not be willing to consider giving you a services contract even if that would be legally possible because they consider the situation too risky wrt. Scheinselbständigkeit.

The is (in theory) a procedure that should give legal certainty about your status: the Statusfeststellungsverfahren. This is done by the German Pension Fund (DRV) who are, however, not really a neutral 3rd party: they are to whom pension fund contributions are paid. Moreover, that status checking procedure is not a once-off thing, if they assign status "freelancer/self-employed" that is for the *one* service provider-customer relationship in question only... And, according to the news, federal politics has expressed the wish that pretty much everyone should be in the employee social insurance (although there is so far no legal basis for this). [According to the numbers published by DRV, the fraction of *voluntary** status checking requests who the DRV decided to be employees has more than doubled from ≈ 20 % in 2007 to 47 % 2014](http://www.scheinselbstaendigkeit.de/scheinselbstaendigkeitde/statistik-zum-statusfeststellungsverfahren.html)
* noone who isn't sure themselves that they are proper freelancers/employ proper freelancers would start this procedure. So these are people who honestly think of themselves as freelancers and just want to have certainty in a legally binding way. (DRV themselves say that the number of people starting this procedure who think they should be employees is negligible)

There are a number of standard questions to be considered when determining whether you have an employment situation or a freelancing services contract. Within those, red flags are e.g. if you'll be at the premises of the customer regularly, during their regular work hours and according to what suits *their* schedule, or if you are doing pretty much the same things like [other] employees of the customer. Another red flag is if you do not have sufficient other customers and are working [for an extended period of time] pretty much exclusively for one customer.
The last criterion has recently changed in practice as the checking now is done for each customer separately, so having several customers may not save you. Not having them will still be a red flag.

OTOH, if you are an established business in Canada *and have employees there* who run the business on the Canadian premises while you are in Germany, and you have plenty of other customers (leaving your German customer's project every so often to take care of the other customers) that's taken as signs that you are *not* employee.